# WCF and authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication

Yesterday I began learning WCF by porting an existing ASP.NET Web Service.

Creating the WCF service was very easy in itself. Approximately an hour after I created my first WCF Service Library project ever, I was already successfully testing my new WCF service in the WCF Test Client.

Now I would like to implement a simple authentication system, but still do not know how. For the sake of simplicity, say my Web Service has three operations: logging in, getting the length of the user's name, and logging out. How do I complete the TODOs in the following code?

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
    public bool Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        /* I have already implemented the function that validades
           whether the user name and password are correct. */
        if (ValidateLogin(userName, password))
        {
            /* TODO: Initiate a session */
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    public int GetUserNameLength()
    {
        /*
           TODO: How to validate whether the user has logged in?
                 How to obtain the name of the user that has logged in?
        */
        int userNameLength = 42;
        return userNameLength;
    }

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    public void Logout()
    {
        /* TODO: How to logout? */
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I am the enemy number one of gross hacks. Please lead me towards conceptually "clean" solutions, regardless of their complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you're following may not be correct with WCF. Based on your approach above, the user is already authenticated as it's able to invoke Login operation. Typically, User shouldn't be allowed to invoke any operation until he/she is auhenticated, but in your approach that's not the case.

Also, the sessions in WCF are client initiated, not server initiated. However, based on your approach they seems to be server initiated.

Here're some resources which sheds more light on WCF Security,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx
Improve wcf security guidance - http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/

If you want to use Custom UserNamePassword validator, here is the link,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx

HTH,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to handle authentication at the application level. If you have a particular business need to do this then go right ahead but if you just trying to ensure an authenticated user is calling your service then use the [build-in WCF authentication mechanisms.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx)

Also, the service contract you are showing is missing this setting in the ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
```

to make the IsInitiating and IsTerminating actually work. Creating session-based WCF services is pretty limiting because you are forcing all the methods in your service to be occur between he Login ... Logout sequence of calls. If you develop multiple services for your application then trying to orchestrate the interaction with each service in its own session can be very error prone.

Comment: @Sixto Saez: I have been trying really hard not to handle authentication at application level. I wrote my own `UserNamePasswordValidator`-derived class, and modified my `App.config` file accordingly. It still didn't work. I would _love_ to be able to handle authentication and actual operations separately.

Comment: It can be tricky configuring custom validation with WCF. You'll need to provide more detail about the binding or bindings you are planning on using for your services. The bindings you pick will determine how you would implement custom validation. This [article explains how to configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) the built-in ASP.NET membership provider for use with WCF. I would start with the sample code in the article to at least get a working WCF service set up. Next, use that sample service to base the services you are writing.

Comment: @Sixto Saez: I am not interested in implementing a full blown `MembershipProvider`. I just want to implement an `UserNamePasswordValidator`. According to the documentation, it should work.

Comment: Just trying to get you started since it seems you're pretty new to WCF. The reason I recommended it the membership provider is that your usage scenario seems very similar. You said to want to provide custom authentication by user name & password and you wanted it done simply. If you can't get the sample [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) working then I'd say your best bet is to find one of the excellent books by either Michelle Bustamante or Clemens Vasters on WCF for an example of what you need.

Comment: @Sixto Saez: The `MembershipProvider` class has too many abstract methods, many of which I am not interested in overriding. I get the feeling that `MembershipProvider` is meant to be used when the WCF Service will be consumed by an ASP.NET Web application that implements its own `MembershipProvider`.

Comment: Not really, the ASP.NET membership provider is a standalone component of .NET framework. The front-end is based on IIS but the actual provider only requires references to the appropriate namespaces in the .NET framework. Check out this [this article if you want to learn more](http://elysianonline.com/programming/using-the-wcf-membership-provider/) about real world usage of this component.

Comment: @Sixto Saez: But, in any case, I don't need to create users, delete users, etc. I just want to validate existing users against an Users table in a database.

Comment: You should probably start a new question like "How can I implement a custom UserNamePasswordValidator in WCF against a existing database user table?" You will need to provide more specifics in that question about the bindings you want your service to use because that will constrain what your options. Good luck!!